# How can I parse this Json data in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

How can I process the following JSON file into a list of LatLong, I have gone through many tutorials but it's not working properly , I have to make a list of the following Latitude and longitude points

'''

```
{
  "snappedPoints": [
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.2784167,
        "longitude": 149.1294692
      },
      "originalIndex": 0,
      "placeId": "ChIJoR7CemhNFmsRQB9QbW7qABM"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": -35.280321693840129,
        "longitude": 149.12908274880189
      },
      "originalIndex": 1,
      "placeId": "ChIJiy6YT2hNFmsRkHZAbW7qABM"
    }
  ]
}
```

'''

Comment: Hello I have answered!

Answer (score 0):

Hello just got to this site:

https://app.quicktype.io/

Select "Dart" language and it will create the classes for you!

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

SnappedPoints snappedPointsFromJson(String str) => SnappedPoints.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String snappedPointsToJson(SnappedPoints data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class SnappedPoints {
    final List<SnappedPoint> snappedPoints;

    SnappedPoints({
        @required this.snappedPoints,
    });

    factory SnappedPoints.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SnappedPoints(
        snappedPoints: List<SnappedPoint>.from(json["snappedPoints"].map((x) => SnappedPoint.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "snappedPoints": List<dynamic>.from(snappedPoints.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class SnappedPoint {
    final Location location;
    final int originalIndex;
    final String placeId;

    SnappedPoint({
        @required this.location,
        @required this.originalIndex,
        @required this.placeId,
    });

    factory SnappedPoint.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SnappedPoint(
        location: Location.fromJson(json["location"]),
        originalIndex: json["originalIndex"],
        placeId: json["placeId"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "location": location.toJson(),
        "originalIndex": originalIndex,
        "placeId": placeId,
    };
}

class Location {
    final double latitude;
    final double longitude;

    Location({
        @required this.latitude,
        @required this.longitude,
    });

    factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Location(
        latitude: json["latitude"].toDouble(),
        longitude: json["longitude"].toDouble(),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "latitude": latitude,
        "longitude": longitude,
    };
}
```